# custom domain for project.firebaseapp.com in ios or android projects for twitter auth

Tags: ios, firebase-authentication, twitter-oauth

Using firebase auth in a project to auth with a provider from a mobile app - based on the provider type - this may open a web view oauth screen., that goes to project.firebaseapp.com url - before it redirects to the actual oauth screen.

It's possible to change a web project and use a custom domain, i.e. app.yourdomain.com - as long as you whitelist it as a redirect and host the domain on gcp (it handles the /auth) and you set the domain as the authDomain in the config.

in the plist - I do not see any authDomain setting - other keys are there for database, and project and so on - is there anyway to set this using the custom parameters or something else so that it will go to app.yourdomain.com before it shows the twitter oauth screen instead of showing project.firestoreapp.com?

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/twitter-login?authuser=3#next_steps seems to indicate that there is a container app that's holding the code to setup the redirect - must be some way to map the custom domain the same way project.firestoreapp.com is pointing to it...

Answer (score 0):

Here's where I ended up

1. You can override it on ios
2. Web works great.
3. Android - Have not yet found out how to do it.

I've submitted an enhancement with the google team.